# Socket io broadcast method broadcasts to sender also from the second action

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I have a confidential code so I am not allowed to post here.
I will give the details of my problem though.

I have a full stack application with PostgreSql, node, express and angular and I am using Socket io for real time notifications of activities made by co users of the application who belong to the same team.

Now I open two chrome windows with the application running. In one window, I add some data. As I am broadcasting that from backend, it is shown in the other window only. But after that, if i do another action say delete any data, it is shown in both the windows. That is socket io acts like it is emitting, not broadcasting.

How can I solve this?

One way is to emit the user email also from the backend and match it to display or not. But that would be a workaround. In my dev environment, the user of both windows will be same though. Would that be causing a problem?

Let me add some demo code:

```
//In client
this.socket.emit('test1') //In test1 component
this.socket.emit('test2') //Test 2 component

//In server
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('test1', (data)=> {
    let message = data + " test1 ";
    socket.broadcast.emit('update', {message:message});
  });
  socket.on('test2', (data) => {
    let message = data + " test1 ";
    socket.broadcast.emit('update', {message:message});
  });
```

So after any one signal, broadcasting stops and socket emits instead of broadcasting.

Comment: Hi Akshay, I've just try to created your example on one of my code base, just used this 2 emit's, it's actually working. Maybe you are making a mistake somewhere else? And if you want maybe you can just try it with `rooms` in socket.io? https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/ check here how you can use.

Comment: Hi Halil, That might be a possibility that I am making some mistake somewhere else. I will do a few more tests and get back.